# How do I start an application from awesome's rc.lua if it's not already running

Tags: awesome-wm

The task is relatively simple. If there is a process with a binary named `x` running, don't start another copy.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with AwesomeWM v4.3, there is also `raise_or_spawn`

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.spawn.html#raise_or_spawn

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function which asynchronously checks whether a process is running and starts it if it's not:

```
function run_if_not_running(program, arguments)
   awful.spawn.easy_async(
      "pgrep " .. program,
      function(stdout, stderr, reason, exit_code)
         naughty.notify { text = stdout .. exit_code }
         if exit_code ~= 0 then
            awful.spawn(program .. " " .. arguments)
         end
   end)
end
```